# Installing Office 2010 through group policy without an msi

Tags: windows, group-policy, microsoft-office-2010

I have been breaking my head for several days now trying to install Microsoft office 2010 through group policy. Unfortunately Microsoft decided it would be fun to release office without an MSI and so I either

1. Need to create an msi for it or
2. Need to install it through a logon script that would run the setup.exe from a network location.

Any advise would be greatlly appreciated. I tried to create a script but even though I double click it and it runs properly, it does not seem to kick in when users log in or when the machine is turned on. Also is there an easy way to create an msi?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers I ended up publishing the software through Group policy with a zap file, not the best solution but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the enterprise version of the software (easily determined by the presence of an "admin" folder in the root directory structure), you can run setup /admin and create an msp file. Put the msp file in the updates directory and run setup (from a logon script or similar); the setup program will now follow whatever settings you put in the msp file.

If you don't have an enterprise version (you get what you pay for); you have to install it manually on every computer (or do something different like AppV).

Comment: With all respect, that simply does not work for 2010 - installing the MSI simply is not supported. You HAVE to either make your own around it, or - the "official" version - use a logon script to run the install. MS really did not do a good job here.

Comment: @TomTom: I'm sorry, are you confused? I didn't say anything about an MSI file. I think you need to read my answer again.

Comment: Well, turn it like you want - the user explicitely asks for exactly NOT what you provide. He does not want to run the logon script. I personally think MS dropped the ball with office setup - no MSI to just publish.

Comment: I agree MS dropped the ball, but you're suggested solution is the exact same as mine. I just gave the 2 cent summary of the MS article you linked. Should I downvote you as well? Also, the question doesn't say anything about not using a login script.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you are "done" - MS does not support MSI installation but pushes people to online script, as you found out. An "EASY" way does not exist - you can take WIX, write your own cusom action and push out the exchange install in it, but this is not an easy way (especially the possible rollback scenario).

I sugest geting the (official) logon script working. The script at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602181.aspx works fine for me - note that "double click" is not the same as starting via GPO (where it runs with elevated priviledges).

Answer (score 0):

I have had good luck using a starup script to install Office with Group Policy.  I usually create a seperate OU called "Software Install OU" just to install software and then after that move the computer to appropriate OU.

1) Configure the "Software Install OU" GPO as follows: Computer Configuration\Policies\Scripts\Startup.  Create a file and name it something like office2010install.cmd.  The contentents should look something like this...
\path to office2010share\setup.exe /config \path to config file, this depends on type of office install Standard.WW, ProProPlus.WW, or Enterprise.WW\config.xml /adminfile \path to Updates folder\office2010.msp  Copy this file to the the "Software Install OU"

2) Use the Office Customization Tool to create a Custom Office Install file (MSP) name it office2010.msp.  Place it in the Updates folder in your Office 2010 Install Share.  At very minimum put in your product key, accept the Lic. Agreement, and Display level to None.

3)  Customize your config.xml.  This depends on which type of Office you want to install.  Need the following information in your config.xml
 -->
 -->

Place it in the appropriate folder such as Standard.WW, ProProPlus.WW, or Enterprise.WW

Test your work.  You can always just run the office2010install.cmd locally on a computer to make sure this works.  Then move on to testing the OU install.